# MacBook Pro mouse pointer periodically hangs; every 3 seconds or so

Tags: macos, mouse, macbook-pro

Every ~3 seconds, my mouse hangs for 0.5 seconds and then jumps to where it should be.

This happens no matter if I'm using my trackpad or Bluetooth mouse or usb mouse.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Because something is eating all the CPU cycles. To try hone it down, have a look at Activity Monitor [Applications/Utilities] Set the View menu to All Processes, then check the tabs for CPU & Memory, sorted by %age. Post pictures if you're not sure what you're seeing.

Comment: CPU load says it's 80-90% idle. windowserver and activity monitor at top.

Comment: Could possibly be something else hanging the USB host controller. Does it happen with nothing connected to USB?

Comment: As @Spiff suspected, it's a usb adapter. 

I'm using `Tuwejia USB C Hub Multiport Adapter with 4kHDMI Output, 1000M RJ45 Gigabit Ethernet, 2USB3.0 Ports ,60W Power Delivery, 5-in-1 USB C Network Adapter` 

I'm just connecting the LAN cable through the adapter, nothing else.

How could i fix the controller not to bother?